# How to pass an optional parameter when using Scalaz OptionT

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am having an issue using OptionT with the below for-comp:

```
for {
  fuOpt1 <- OptionT(...)
  fuOpt2 <- OptionT(...)
  fuOpt3 <- OptionT(getF3(fuOpt1.optionalInt))
} yield agg(fuOpt1, fuOpt2, fuOpt3)
```

The problem is in getF3 which looks like:

```
def getF3(a: Int): Future[Option[F3]]
```

The property on fuOpt1.optionalInt is Option[Int].

**What do I need to change to get this for comp to work correctly?**

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if (fuOpt1.optionalInt.isDefined) OptionT(getF3(fuOpt1.optionalInt.get)) else Future.successful(None).liftM[OptionT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options.

Add a generator to your for comprehension:

```
for {
  fuOpt1 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  fuOpt2 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  a <- OptionT.optionT(Future.successful(fuOpt1.optionalInt))
  fuOpt3 <- OptionT.optionT(getF3(a))
} yield agg(fuOpt1, fuOpt2, fuOpt3)
```

Or use a fold on fuOpt1.optionalInt, which is close to what you tried:

```
for {
  fuOpt1 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  fuOpt2 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  fuOpt3 <- fuOpt1.optionalInt.fold(OptionT.none[Future, F3])(a => OptionT.optionT(getF3(a)))
} yield agg(fuOpt1, fuOpt2, fuOpt3)
```

Or wrap your `getF3` in a version that accepts an option:

```
def getF3Opt(a: Option[Int]): Future[Option[F3]] = {
  a.fold(Future.successful(None: Option[F3]))(getF3)
}

for {
  fuOpt1 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  fuOpt2 <- OptionT.optionT(...)
  fuOpt3 <- OptionT.optionT(getF3Opt(fuOpt1.optionalInt))
} yield agg(fuOpt1, fuOpt2, fuOpt3)
```

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis is that if `fuOpt1.optionalInt == None` then your for-comprehension should "fail" with `Future.successful(None)`. If this hypothesis fit your situation than you can write:

```scala
for {
  fuOpt1 <- OptionT(...)
  fuOpt2 <- OptionT(...)
  optionalInt <- OptionT(fuOpt1.optionalInt.point[Future])
  fuOpt3 <- OptionT(getF3(optionalInt))
} yield agg(fuOpt1, fuOpt2, fuOpt3)
```